# How can I repair a leaking wall valve for future laundry sink?

Tags: leak, plumbing-fixture

Just found the stub for an unbuilt sink in our laundry room is leaking. Tightened but moisture continues to collect below the valve. Not sure about next steps to explore before calling a plumber. 
You can see it here:

[image: moisture below valve]

Comment: Please provide a clearer photo of the valve connection point (from the side). Is the water coming from the valve discharge nipple, the handle area, or the pipe joint?

Answer (score 1):

Unscrew it & likely the short pipe it's attached to & put in a new short pipe with Teflon Tape wrapping both ends & screw-on a nice new Quarter-turn ball valve. You'll be solid for decades.

Answer (score 0):

3/8" compression, brass cap (possibly 1/2"). No need for a plumber unless the valve itself leaks. Even then, you might just have to tighten the packing nut a bit.

[image]

<sub>hardwarestore.com</sub>

Comment: To clarify, this would be installed where a supply line would normally go as a temporary fix until the valve can be replaced. It appears that the seal has failed.

Comment: And this technically isn't a compression fitting. It's just a cap that goes where a compression fitting would normally be. You'd want to use teflon tape to seal it.

Comment: @isherwood - Quite right, it's merely the same threads; you'll still need to use sealant.

Comment: This got me curious. Is this an Army-Navy (AN) thread? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN_thread

Comment: @isherwood - Nope, those are flare fittings (which, yes, those are a type of compression fitting, but IME that's not what a plumber means when they say *compression fitting*). Here's a [compression thread chart](http://cloudfront.zorotools.com/img/zoro_tips/compression.pdf).